# Существуют ли матерные слова в 36-ричной системе счисления?

Tags: php, веб-программирование

```
base_convert($id, 10, 36);
```

Использую преобразованный ID из таблицы MySQL в 36-ричной системе счисления в качестве уникального короткого URL. Может ли пользователь увидеть какое-то неприятное слово в таком URL?

**UPDATE**
Кажется уже разобрался, число 739172. Мда, есть там матерные слова.

Comment: Чего нет-то, если все буквы валидны?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Насколько я понял, итоговая цель не узнать, есть ли матерные слова в 36-ричной системе счисления, а сгенерировать ID, таких слов не содержащие, на базе числа-идентификатора из БД.

Есть библиотека, которая занимается генерацией таких ID - [hashids](https://github.com/ivanakimov/hashids.php) - и у нее есть встроенная [защита от бранных слов](https://github.com/ivanakimov/hashids.php#curses-):

> This code was written with the intent of placing created ids in
>   visible places, like the URL. Therefore, the algorithm tries to avoid
>   generating most common English curse words by generating ids that
>   never have the following letters next to each other: c, f, h, i, s, t, u

Защита нацелена на английские слова, но идея настолько проста, что ее легко расширить без составления словарей.

Пример использования библиотеки:

```
$hashids = new Hashids('my secret key'); 
$id = $hashids->encode(1, 2, 3); // o2fXhV 
$numbers = $hashids->decode($id); // [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 16):

36-ричной системой счисления можно записать любое слово из английского языка, в т.ч. и нецензурные. Да ещё и на цифры останется!

Например,

- число 739172<sub>10</sub> записывается как FUCK<sub>36</sub>,
- число 591428<sub>10</sub> записывается как COCK<sub>36</sub>,
- число 43427410<sub>10</sub> равно PUSSY<sub>36</sub>.

Разумеется, существуют и более приличные числа, как пример,

- 3498439885<sub>10</sub> = 1luvPHP<sub>36</sub> (I love PHP).

Таким образом можно закодировать даже целые фразы. А для преобразования можно воспользоваться функцией **base_convert** из PHP, как в вопросе, если второй и третий параметры поменять местами.

Comment: Может быть что нибудь посоветуете?

Comment: Лучше пишите ваши айдишники в 10-тичной системе. Букв нету — слово составить трудно.

Comment: а ещё можно использовать 16-ричную систему счисления. Из A, B, C, D, E, F нельзя составить матное слово.

Comment: Только вероятность получить такой ID – ничтожная. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin Вероятность получить матерное число 100% если речь идёт о последовательном переборе: 1,2,3... 739172 -> f*ck. Ну а вообще эту проблему решить невозможно, т.к. что то оскорбительное может получиться и без мата. В итоге составить блэклист не получится. Если число длинное то конечно пользователь не будет его разглядывать, а вот сервисы по генерации коротких url наверняка кого то посылали и не раз :)

Comment: Что неприличного в 43427410? А вот 3498439885 может стоить работы

Answer (score 0):

Можно легко найти любое получаемое слово в любой системе счисления используя функцию обратного преобразования из строкового представления в int. Например в javascript это функция parseInt:

```
parseInt("bad", 36)
parseInt("good", 36)
parseInt("fuck", 36)
parseInt("cock", 36)
parseInt("pussy", 36)
```

Можно проверить в консоли (ctrl+shift+i) не отходя от кассы.

Далее просто берем словарь обсценной лексики, для каждого слова получаем число — используем его как ключ в хеш-массиве (лучше использовать Set (множество), если позволяет язык — он экономнее, так-как содержит только ключи без сопоставленных им значений). Теперь можно легко проверить является ли число — матерным. Можно делать и в лоб, но использование в работе Set с ключами-словами (словаря «плохих» слов), выйдет дороже по памяти, нежели использование Set c ключами-числами.